# Convert 3 integers into Date variable in Java

Tags: java, date, integer

Currently I have tried converting it to a `String` in the correct format and then trying to convert the `String` into a `Date` variable.

`startYear, startMonth, startDay` are the 3 `ints`

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(startYear, startMonth-1, startDay);
Date date = calendar.getTime();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
String strDate = df.format(date);
```

However, I'm not sure how to go about converting the `String` into a `Date` in the format `yyyy/mm/dd`.

I feel like I may be going about this in a roundabout way...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Answer (score 1):

`Date` does not have any concept of a format, it is a container for the number of milliseconds from the Unix epoch.  When you display a `Date` object it uses the current local's default format to display.  This is basically use for information purpose.

If you want to format the `Date` in some kind of format, you use a some kind of `DateFormatter` which produces a `String` representation of the `Date` in the given format.

Stop trying to "format" the `Date` object (so you end up with a formatted `Date` object), it won't work, it's not how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class?

[http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime(int](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime%28int), int, int, int, int)

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(startYear, startMonth, startDay, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: I suggest passing one more argument in that example line of code, a [DateTimeZone](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html) object. Otherwise the JVM's default time zone is used in constructing the DateTime object. Example: `DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" )`

Comment: The OP didn't use one in the example, so I omitted it in the response.    If it were my application, I would generally use an explicit TZ as well.